# How to export product url in Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, products, product-urls

I have exported my products from the admin panel of the magento, but there is no product url.

Is it possible to export every product url??

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL for import. 
For example, in `eav_attribute` you can find attribute_id for product url_key. Default value is 126

Further, you may use this SQL:

```
SELECT 
catalog_product_entity.entity_id, 
catalog_product_entity_varchar.store_id, 
catalog_product_entity_varchar.value as 'URL_KEY' 
FROM 
`catalog_product_entity` inner JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar 
ON 
catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id 
WHERE attribute_id = 126
```

The result will smth like this:
[image]